# Calculus Derivative - Finding unknown constants

Tags: calculus, derivatives, constants

Determine the constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ so that the curve defined by
$y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ has a local maximum at the point $(2, 4)$ and a point of inflection at the origin. Sketch the curve.
I know to create different equations and use substitution to find the unknown values, but am unsure on how to get the equations.

Comment: The first clue tells us that $ \ f'(2) \ = 0 \ , $ giving us a relation between $ \ a \ , \ b \ , $ and $ \ c \ $ .  The second clue, $ \ f''(0) = 0 \ , $ will give us a relation between $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ .  Knowing that $ \ f(2) = 4 \ $ and $ \ f(0) = 0 \ $  will resolve the values of all the coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let C be the curve in question. C has a local max at (2, 4) if y'(2) = 0 :

First y(2) = 4 ==> 8a + 4b + 2c + d = 4. Second y'(2) = 0 ==> 12a + 4b + c = 0. C has an

inflection point at (0,0) means: y''(0) = 0 ==> 2b = 0. So b = 0. Also (0,0) is on C so:

y(0) = 0 ==> d = 0. So: 8a + 2c = 4 and 12a + c = 0 ==> a = -1/4 and c = 3. So:

(a, b, c, d ) = (-1/4, 0, 3, 0).

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $(2,4)$ and $(0,0)$ **lies on the curve** gives you your first two equations:

$$y(2) = 4,$$
$$y(0) = 0$$

A **local maximum point** at $x = 2$ gives you your third equation:
$$y'(2) = 0$$

A **point of inflection** at $x = 0$ gives you your fourth:

$$y''(0) = 0$$

Substitute in to set up a system of $4$ linear equations in $a,b,c,d$.

---

There are some observations you can make to simplify things.

Notice that $y(0) = 0 \implies a(0)^3 + b(0)^2 + c(0) + d = 0 \implies d = 0$.

Notice also that $y''(0) = 0 \implies 6a(0) + 2b = 0 \implies b = 0$. This leaves us with:

$$y = ax^3 + cx$$

which can be more easily solved with $y(2) = 4$ and $y'(2) = 0$.

Comment: You don't need a whole system of equations, since they were nice and already told us, for instance, what $ \ d \ $ is... :)

Comment: Indeed, now that I realize. I'll add that in! But I'll present the more abstract solution anyway, just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

First, differentiate:
$$y' = 3ax^2+2bx+c$$
Since we want a local maximum at $(2, 4)$, set the expression for the derivative equal to $0$ and substitute $2$ in for $x$.
$$0=12a+4b+c$$
Now, an inflection point at $(0,0$). Differentiate again:
$$y''=6ax+2b$$
Since we want an inflection point, set this expression equal to $0$ and substitute $0$ in for $x$:
$$0=2b$$
Also, remember that we want $y(2)=4$ and $y(0)=0$. So, we have a system of equations:

- $4=a(2)^3+b(2)^2+c(2)+d$
- $0=a(0)^3+b(0)^2+c(0)+d$
- $0=12a+4b+c$
- $0=2b$

Now just solve the system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since the curve has a point of inflection at the origin, it must pass through $(0,0)$ and so $y(0)=0$, implying $d=0$.

Then, the curve also passes through $(2,4)$, so $y(2)=4$ or $$8a+4b+2c=4.\tag1$$

Well you also want your curve to have a maximum at $(2,4)$. This means that the derivative, or $$y'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c,$$ must be zero at $x=2$. So, $y'(2)=0$ or $$12a+4b+c=0.\tag2$$

Lastly, you want to have a point of inflection at the origin so the second derivative must have $x=0$ as a root of odd multiplicity. Now, $$y''(x)=6ax+2b$$ and we require $y''(0)=0$, implying $b=0$.

Substituting back into $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $$4a+c=2\tag{$*$}$$and $$12a+c=0\tag{$**$}.$$This is a simple linear system which you can solve to get $a=-1/4$ and $c=3$.

To sum up, $a=-1/4$, $b=0$, $c=3$, $d=0$ and so the required curve is given by $$y=-\frac14x^3+3x$$ which you can easily sketch since you know the stationary points and can instantly find the roots.